# Prevent screen capture software from monitoring input fields

Tags: security, desktop-recording

The obstacle I am trying to overcome is with screen recording software that monitors the computer while in use. Workstations use common technologies like RDP and Citrix XenApp. There are a few details which should be seen by the user via a browser window input fields but are best left unrecorded. Physical attacks aside, is there any standard way of handling this?

I did question printing said information and using stylesheets to hide it from the screen, but this really isn't a viable option.

Comment: If something is drawn on the screen, it can be captured in software and analyzed. There was an application on the market, which allowed you to capture the block of the screen and recognize the text instantly.

Comment: This is the trouble. I'm not expecting to stop everything, but I was wondering if there was a subtle hint that I could implement that some software might respect. For example, <input type="text" name="cardNumber capture="no" /> at which point the marketplace software would respect this and block this element from the recording.

Comment: what's the reason for false feeling of security? If I can take the application and capture data right from the screen in seconds, then your protection is fake. Totally different approach must be taken to protecting this data. But even then the general rule applies - whatever information appears on general-purpose device (PC system) is not yours anymore and you can't control it.

Comment: Think of an outsourced call centre where the agent needs to input personal information such as a credit card. But also to monitor compliance the systems are recording the actions taking place to ensure systems are used the way they should be. It's not ideal, sure, but anything to limit damage seems like a good thing.